# ASP.Net Core 3.1 and global view method

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, partial-views, html-helper

The code `@await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Shared/_Toast.cshtml", new ToastMessage() { Caption = "Hello", Message = "World" })` renders a partial view with arguments. It shows a Bootstrap toast message, which I intend to use everywhere.

Now is it possible to reduce that line to something like `@MyHelpers.ShowToastMessage(new ToastMessage() { Caption = "Hello", Message = "World" })`? I don't want to use View Components (overkill). Also @functions block seems to be local only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can custom a htmlhelper in your app.

```
namespace App.Helpers
{
    public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
    {
        public static IHtmlContent ShowToastMessage(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, ToastMessage model)
        {
            string str = "<div> "+ model.Caption + " " + model.Message + " <div/>";            
            return new HtmlString(str);
        }
    }
}
```

In your view:

```
@using App.Helpers


@await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Shared/_Toast.cshtml", new ToastMessage() { Caption = "Hello", Message = "World" })

@Html.ShowToastMessage(new ToastMessage() { Caption = "Hello", Message = "World" })
```

If your `_Toast.cshtml` contains other html elements, then you can use [TagBuilder Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.tagbuilder?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to create.